# How to randomly move the sprite to a certain point in the console C#

Tags: c#, console-application

I have a sprite which moves randomly in the console. It moves left, right, up or down at a time

.Let's suppose that sprite starts to move from **position X=5**,**position Y=5**

how can I make it go at a certain position in the screen for example at **position X=20** and **position Y=10**?

```
public void Draw()
{
    Console.SetCursorPosition(PositionX, PositionY);
    Console.Write(Sprite);
}

public void RandomMove()
{
    var number = Random.Next(1, 5);
    switch (number)
    {
        case 1:
        PositionX++; //Move Down
        break;
        case 2:
        PositionX--; Move Up
        break;
        case 3:
        PositionY--; Move Left
        break;
        case 4:
        PositionY++; Move Right
        break;
    }
}
while(true)
{
    RandomMove();
    Draw()
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Is the sprite one character big?

Comment: yes it is. As a sprite I use 'A'

Answer (score 2):

### Use Random to generate a random position

Take a look at Victor Laio's code example there. You need to provide two parameters to `Next`, a **lower** and an **upper bound**.

### Make sure to put the cursor into a position that is visible on the screen.

In order to achieve that you can use the following static properties on the `Console` class:

- `Console.WindowTop` - Gets the **topmost** visible position.
- `Console.WindowLeft` - Gets the **topmost** visible position.
- `Console.WindowWidth` - Gets the **number of visible characters** in a row.
- `Console.WindowHeight` - Gets the **number of visible rows** in the console.

### Put the cursor to the desired position

You can use the `SetCursorPosition` method. For example: `Console.SetCursorPosition(10, 10);`

## Putting it all together

The following example sets the cursor to a random position on every keypress. Notice that I do not subtract 1 from `maxLeft` because `Random.Next` takes an exclusive upper bound.

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        while (true)
        {
            Console.ReadKey();
            int minLeft = Console.WindowLeft;
            int maxLeft = Console.WindowLeft + Console.WindowWidth;
            int minTop = Console.WindowTop;
            int maxTop = Console.WindowTop + Console.WindowHeight;
            Console.SetCursorPosition(r.Next(minLeft, maxLeft), r.Next(minTop, maxTop));
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Random()](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.random?view=netframework-4.7.2) class to get random values to your application. Below you can see an exemple:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int random = rnd.Next(1, 13);
```

Comment: At the moment I can get the sprite moving randomly in the console. but the only problem is that i don't know how to make it to go to another point